# win7 show "open with" sub menu

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

How can I always show the "open with" sub menu instead of the "open with..." for a particular file extension?

Always show
[image]

Not
[image]

EDIT:
To be more specific, let's say I have a ".abc" file and I want its context menu to have Open With > "Notepad, Excel". How can I do this? I don't mind editing the registry if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You get just `Open with...` if Windows has no idea how to open a file.  You get the submenu if Windows has some info on the file and can present a list of one or more options.

You cannot always show the submenu because for files unknown to Windows, there would be nothing to list.

If you are looking to find a way to have certain actions appear on the context menu for every file, this can be done by adding a HKCR entry for `*` in the registry.

Comment: thanks for the answer but could you please be more specific? please see edited question. Thank you